# call api or getServerSideProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

let's assume I have a blog-details screen and I will populate that using `getServerSideProps`. Should I send a request to my `/api/` route and then in the API route connect to the database and return the datas? Or just connect to the database from the `getServerSideProps`?

I have seen very popular developers send the request to the api from `getServerSideProps` function but that doesn't make sense to me! why not just access the database from the `getServerSideProps` function and do everything their that an API route can do?

Answer (score 2):

I quote document from Next.js:
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering

> Note: You should not use fetch() to call an API route in
> getServerSideProps. Instead, directly import the logic used inside
> your API route. You may need to slightly refactor your code for this
> approach.
>
> Fetching from an external API is fine!